# Run multiplicative decompose using lapply in r

Tags: r, time-series, lapply

I have a data with 3 columns
account: ~1500 of them (numeric ids)
month: 24month of data (date time format)
sales: monthly sales for each account

I want to run multiplicative decompose at account level. I curated the following from web search. ([Decompose Time series into Trend, Seasonality and Random for multiple groups in R for monthly data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787432/decompose-time-series-into-trend-seasonality-and-random-for-multiple-groups-in))

```
tss <- tapply(data$sales, data$account, ts, start = c(2021, 5), frequency = 4)
dcs <- lapply(tss, decompose)
```

The above equation runs additive type by default. I want to run multiplicative type. I also came about another solution

```
dcs <- lapply(names(tss), function(x) {decompose(tss[, x], type = "additive")})
```

but this seems to not work because of

1. nested list in tss
2. the id's are characters transformed from numeric values which is throwing an error

I am expecting a simpler solution like the following but unfortunately this doesn't work.

```
dcs <- lapply(tss, decompose(type = "multiplicative")
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add optional arguments to a function within lapply separated by comma's:

```
dcs <- lapply(tss, decompose, type = "multiplicative")
```